# Android: What is meaning of Uniform, mat4 and vec4 in Open GL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, embedded, shader

In this code (from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) website):

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;   \n" 
"attribute vec4 vPosition;  \n" +
"void main(){               \n" +
" gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition; \n" +

"}  \n";
```

What is meaning of `uniform` and `mat` 4?

and What is meaning of `attribute` and `vec4` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Uniform` is a value that is set per draw call. For instance you may set a color for the whole shape you draw and for all the shader calls the uniform value will be the same. This is opposed to the `attribute` for instance which is per vertex or having a `var` which is per fragment but must be set in the vertex shader.
- `mat4` is a type representing a 4x4 matrix. It consists of 16 floating point values. That means it needs to be passed to shader as a `float[16]` type or `float*` pointer which contains at least 16 floating point values.
- `attribute` indicates a value that will be passed per vertex. For each attribute you must bind its id, enable it and set the pointer to the attribute from the CPU. The values will then be different per vertex. Some common uses are position, texture coordinates, normals, vertex colors...
- `vec4` is a type representing a 4 dimensional vector. It consists of 4 floating point values. It can be used for many things such as position, normal.. even color is usually of type `vec4`.

Comment: Which language is it in which we write the Shader code?

Comment: Depends, search for the shader languages. This one seems like the GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language).

Comment: Why is `vec4` required when position can be determined by only three parameters: X, Y and Z?

Comment: It is not required on the input, it is required for 4x4 matrix computation as to multiply the matrix A and B the number of rows in B must equal number of columns in A, B in this case being a vec4 with a single column having 4 rows. This is just pure math. The output is set by default to vec4 and can not be changed so in any case it needs to be typecast to vec4 in the end. So basically the "attribute vec4 vPosition" could be "attribute vec2 vPosition".

Comment: I can't understand "B in this case a `vec4`  with a single column having 4 rows ". and When do we multiply these vectors?

Comment: A vector is actually representing a marix with a single column and D rows that is why you need a 4D vector to be able to multiply with a 4x4 matrix. You do that in the shader you posted in main function.

Comment: uMVPMatrix * vPosition is your matrix product as A*B where A is a 4x4 matrix named uMVPMatrix and B is a 4x1 matrix named vPosition.